# Get context in usual Javascript function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there way to get **context** in usual Javascript function (in function which is not being rendered)?

I have function which doesn't render anything (it downloads .csv) which uses hook (using hook is not correct solution)

```
const archiveExportCSV=async(tasks)=> {
    let context = useContext(StaticsContext);
    //... some code which uses context
    Helpers.download(csv,'test.csv','data:text/csv;charset=utf-8');
};
```

and I am calling it in component:

```
<button type="button" 
        className="btn-reset"
        title="export to .csv"
        onClick={()=>archiveExportCSV(tasks)}>
```

It is wrong because function is neither a *React function component* or a *custom React Hook function*. **Is there any way how get context in callable function or I have to pass arguments from context manually as arguments?**

Comment: hooks can only be used inside of a functional component bur not inside of a handler. You need to pass the relevant context to the function as arguments.

Comment: @trixn So as I wrote there is no other way than passing it as arguments like `archiveExportCSV(tasks, somethingFromContext)` right?

Comment: Yes that is how you need to do it. There is no other way.

Comment: Technically, it does not have to be an argument, just a variable in scope (including closure variables), but anything more complicaded would be impractical for this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call hooks in a handler but you can pass the context to your function when it gets called. Hooks need to be called unconditionally and on every render of your component in the same order as react references them by that. Having them in a handler violates that:

```
const MyComponent = ({tasks}) => {
    const context = useContext(StaticsContext);
    const handleClick = useCallback(() => archiveExportCSV(tasks, context), [tasks, context]);

    return (
        <button 
            type="button" 
            className="btn-reset"
            title="export to .csv"
            onClick={handleClick}
        >
            Click me
        </button>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Didn't realize that button can be part of export component which gives me valid React component where I can use Hooks. So the export function can be part of the button component or called by `useCallback()`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for alternatives to explicit arguments - if a function can be created INSIDE a component, it can access all variable in scope (a.k.a. a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)):

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const context = useContext(StaticsContext);

  const archiveExportCSV = async(tasks) => {
    //... some code which uses context
  };
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for idea. It's simpler solution than using `useCallback` hook.

Comment: useCallback is a performance optimization, it shouldn't affect any business logic whether it's used or not